# Eclipse IDE set up only methods of class be visible in package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, installation, package-explorer

Eclipse IDE. When I click on java class file in package explorer, it opens (unfolds) inside of package explorer and I can see the list of classes, methods and variables (fields) which are in this class.
My question is - **can I set it up this way: to only Methods be visible (no fields in the list)?**. It could really help with navigation inside big classes. I am sorry, too much trash results in google.

[image: Image representation of what i want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Java Element Filters Dialog](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-java-element-filters.htm) :

> This dialog lets you define Java element filters for the Package Explorer view and other Java views.

There should be a "Filters..." toolbar button to open this dialog ...

Comment: Thank you, I have found what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you! I have found it here (in Eclipse Luna 4.4.0):
[image]

Now when "fields" are marked they are no longer visible in class list.

Answer (score 1):

The Package Explorer in the Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 on Microsoft Windows XP replaced Filters... option with a Customize View.. option.

[image: The Package Explorer Dropdown menu]

[image: Eclipse Version]

Comment: ya, that may be helpful for XP users. Thank you!